# How to format numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, spatial

I have data that looks like this

```
listL= array([array([-12939613.07220617,   3962855.50690994]),
       array([-12939614.67349505,   3962828.80807231]),
       array([-12939484.00289515,   3962828.1637531 ]),
       array([-12939484.98046737,   3962854.91251931]),

print(type(listL)) -> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(listL[0])) -> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(listL[0][0])) -> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I have a second piece of data that looks like this:

```
A = array([[ 73.87682896,   8.55827956],
       [ 57.43741519,  10.40224912],
       [ 87.88970753,  75.42971056],

print(type(A)) -> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(A[0])) -> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(A[0][0])) -> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

The types are the same across both sets of data, but I have a function that works with 'A', but not with 'listL' and I cannot figure out why.

```
A[spatial.KDTree(A).query(coordinate)[1]]
```

works, but

```
listL[spatial.KDTree(listL).query(coordinate)[1]]
```

returns the error:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: The `type` doesn't help much.  Look at `shape` and `dtype` instead.  `listL` Iwhich  is missing a `])`) is a 1d object dtype array (shape (4,).  `A` is a 2d array of numbers, shape (3,2).  `np.stack(listL)` should produce a (4,2) numeric array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListL` is in some respects a pathological structure, it is an array of arrays where a 2D array is expected.

`numpy/scipy` goes to some lengths to graciously accept most things that can be interpreted as 2D array, for example if you repace `KDTRee(ListL)` with `KDTree(list(ListL))` it works.

Why does it work? Because `list(listL)` behaves like most "essentially 2D" structures (like lists of lists etc.). We can send it through `array` or `asarray` or `asanyarray` etc. to obtain a genuine 2D array.

```
>>> np.array(list(listL))
array([[-12939613.07220617,   3962855.50690994],
       [-12939614.67349505,   3962828.80807231],
       [-12939484.00289515,   3962828.1637531 ],
       [-12939484.98046737,   3962854.91251931]])
>>> np.array(list(listL)).shape
(4, 2)
```

An array of arrays is one of the few cases left that still trip up the array conversion machinery:

```
>>> np.array(listL)
array([array([-12939613.07220617,   3962855.50690994]),
       array([-12939614.67349505,   3962828.80807231]),
       array([-12939484.00289515,   3962828.1637531 ]),
       array([-12939484.98046737,   3962854.91251931])], dtype=object)
>>> np.array(listL).shape
(4,)
```

We can see despite our attempt to convert to an ordinary array, `listL` keeps reporting its shape as 1D. Which appears to be what triggers the exception you are observing.